# Does the weak force get transmitted at speeds less than $c$?

Tags: mass, standard-model, weak-interaction, carrier-particles

The force carrier of EM is the photon (or off-shell photons at least). These are massless field disturbances. However the force carriers in Weak interactions are the $W$ and $Z$ bosons. Having mass, do they transmit information at subluminal speeds then?

Comment: Yes. (I wish we could write one word comments, but I have to extend it to cross the word limit.)

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is here.  You seem to be asking whether the propagation of a *field* (of weak force) can propagate faster than a particle with mass?   By contrast, photons may carry *energy* , but  the E-M *field* produced by an electron cannot shift faster than the electron does.  There's a difference between transfer of force/energy and the existence of a field.

Comment: "You seem to be asking whether the propagation of a field (of weak force) can propagate faster than a particle with mass?"

Yes this is precisely what I am asking. Are the virtual W,Z bosons that carry information from point A to point B able to do so at speed c (the speed of causality afterall)? Or is information transferred at speeds less than c between two events (I won't say particles here as that gets sort of messy in QFT).

Comment: I would also not say that the electron example is precisely true. An electron moves at some speed v < c of course. But even from a classical perspective information about its wherabouts is communicated (as far as I understand anyways) to surrounding spacetime at speed c.

In QFT, the EM field is not "produced" by the electron, it exists independent of any charged object, but rather it can be "disturbed" by field excitations in the electron-positron field by means of its interaction term J*A. Can you flesh out your answer a bit please?

Comment: Your question is seriously malformed. Electromagnetism is long-ranged:  long-distance interactions may amount to classical, speed-of-light signals. EW interactions, by dramatic contrast, are very short ranged, so fractions of a fermi, which invalidates any notion of information transfer speed. Please clarify your question by asking a focussed  one which could admit answers beyond "lies-to-children".

Comment: I'm assuming that you are saying that a field excitation (virtual particle) having narrowly defined speed (or more traditionally momentum) involves too large a spread in position-space to speak reasonably of transmission distance.

I've noticed that in QFT the entire idea of wave-packets seems to have disappeared. So I guess what I am asking is what is physically happening if the Field-theory is still local, but we can't speak reasonably in terms of information propagation?

(I got out of physics quite a number of years ago, but am now enjoying getting back into it for interest sake).

Answer (score 3):

The weak interaction is mediated by a field, not by particles, despite the poetic/lazy language that physicists sometimes use. The W and Z *particles* are special manifestations of the W and Z *fields* that mediate the weak interaction, but the fields are not made of particles. Analogy: a tornado is a special manifestation of the dynamics of the atmosphere, but the dynamics of the atmosphere is not made of tornadoes.

With that clarification in mind, we can address the question using a simplified model in which the mediating field is a single scalar field $\phi$ whose equation of motion is
$$
 \partial^2\phi+m^2\phi\propto J,
$$
where:

- $m$ is the mass of the corresponding particle ($m\sim 90\,\times$ the mass of a proton),
- $J$ is the appropriate "charge density" of the quarks/leptons (using the word "charge" in a generalized sense, not referring to electrostatics at all),
- the units are such that $\hbar=c=1$.

This equation of motion has two properties relevant to the question:

1. For simplicity, temporarily think of $\phi$ as a classical field (instead of as a quantum field). Unlike waves in the electromagnetic field (which would have $m=0$ in this analogy), waves in the field $\phi$ are dispersive: an initially localized wavepacket spreads out along the direction of motion as it propagates, so the leading edge travels faster than the trailing edge. **The group velocity (speed of the wavepacket's centroid) is less than the speed of light, but the leading edge still moves as the speed of light.**
2. For simplicity, temporarily think of the "charge density" $J$ as a static classical quantity. The "force field" of such a source depends on the distance $r$ from the source like $\phi\sim (e^{-mr})/r$. Since $m\sim 90\,\times$ the mass of a proton, this "force" is completely negligible on scales larger than the size of a proton.

In reality, $\phi$ is a *quantum* field, and the quarks/leptons that define $J$ are *quantum* entities, so the idea of the "speed of transmission of the weak force" is even fuzzier than point 1 already emphasized, especially since its extremely short range (point 2) keeps it firmly on the *quantum* side of the spectrum of behaviors. We can still say that the influence cannot be transmitted any faster than the speed of light, but to say much beyond that would require reframing the question in terms that make more sense for a quantum field that behaves in a very non-classical way — not like classical particles *or* classical fields.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this. So why is it that the wave-packet idea disappears in quantum field theory, and what is the way you think about the interaction from a QFT perspective?

Also, I'm cool giving you the bounty, but I'm brand new to this so how do I do that lol.

Comment: @mebaker The wavepacket concept still works in qft whenver the particle-concept is a good approximation, but it's not always a good approximation. We talk about the inside of a proton like it were a bag of three quarks, but thats not really accurate. A more accurate picutre is one in which the number of quarks is not even well-defined, much less their locations.

Comment: @mebaker The field that mediates the weak interaction (or any other interaction) can be in a particle-like state in some circumstances, or in a wave-like state in ither circumstances, but usually it's neither. You can think of it as a quantum superposition of different numbers of particles, or of different wavepackets (but not a superposition in the classical sense), and its entangled with the quarks and leptons. Words cant really describe what the math says. We can try  to develop new intuition based on the math, but I'm not sure anybody really has  great intuition about it.

Comment: "We can try to develop new intuition based on the math, but I'm not sure anybody really has great intuition about it"

That is really unfortunate, after so many years out of the research world, this is precisely what I was hoping to get :(

Answer (score -2):

Yes it does. Massive particles cannot move at lightspeed, although arbitrarily close to it if they have enough energy.

Comment: Does this argument still apply to the off-shell "particles". It seems to me the answer must be a little more nuanced than yes or no, as the precise mass-energy of these field-disturbances is not defined, even though the events that result from their transmission can be.